# Trying to obtain the cell address that has a hyper link in

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA in an Excel workbook to open VLC on a specific music video without getting the MS warning about 'are you sure this is safe'.
I have the code to run it, and am attempting to call it from a hyperlink.
I don't want to use a button, too many videos, so decided on a hyperlink.
The problem I have is the Hyperlink when clicked doesn't make the cell active. I'm using ActiveCell to select the artist and track name (column + ActiveCell.row). I can't find anywhere that will give me the cell reference of the hyperlink used.
Created a defined Names range for the column of hyperlinks.
Since the hyperlink doesn't make the cell active, the code reverts to the first in the range.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Call Start_VLC
End Sub

Public Sub Start_VLC()
    Dim strProgName As String
    Dim strPlaceTitle As String
    Dim strLoc As String
    Dim ActCol As String
    Dim ActRow As Double

    strLoc = Range("f1").Value & Range("B" & ActiveCell.row).Value & " - " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.row).Value & ".mp4"    'F1 = MP4 location and B&C title
    strProgName = "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 'vlc location
    strPlaceTitle = strLoc 'MP4 location
    
    MsgBox "Active Cell = " & ActiveCell.row 'just to keep track
    MsgBox "strLoc = " & strLoc
    MsgBox "strProgName = " & strProgName
    MsgBox "strPlace Title = " & strPlaceTitle

    Call Shell("""" & strProgName & """ """ & strPlaceTitle & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Any suggestion welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`Hyperlink.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.range) property:

> Returns a Range object that represents the range that the specified hyperlink is attached to.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
   Start_VLC Row:=Target.Range.Row
End Sub

Public Sub Start_VLC(ByVal Row As Long)
   strLoc = Range("f1").Value & Range("B" & Row).Value & " - " & Range("C" & Row).Value & ".mp4"  
   ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the total solution I went with.
It includes the hyperlink pasting and video calling.
It may be longwinded but I'm a happy soul.
Cheers BigBen

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Call Start_VLC
End Sub
Public Sub Start_VLC()
    Dim strProgName As String
    Dim strPlaceTitle As String
    Dim strLoc As String
    Dim ActCol As String
    Dim ActRow As Double
    
    strLoc = Range("f1").Value & Range("B" & ActiveCell.row).Value & " - " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.row).Value & ".mp4"    'F1 = MP4 location and B&C title
    strProgName = "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 'vlc location
    strPlaceTitle = strLoc 'MP4 location
    
    Call Shell("""" & strProgName & """ """ & strPlaceTitle & """", vbNormalFocus)
     
End Sub

Sub HyperlinkFill() 'Create hyperlinks to start vVLC video from click
Dim LastRow, HyLRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Range("J1") + 5 'J1 has the total number of videos available & hyperlinks start on row 6 currently to row 3352
    
    For HyLRow = 6 To LastRow
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Searching").Range("I" & HyLRow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'Searching'!I" & HyLRow, TextToDisplay:="PLAY NOW"
    Next HyLRow
    

End Sub
```